# Can M12 lenses work with with Rasberry Pi V3 camera?

Tags: camera

The V3 camera does have autofocus, but will it work once I mount a 5mm M12 lens on it for zoom? I'm planning to 3D print a housing for the camera with a c connector for my M12 lenses. In short, do lenses affect how the autofocus works?

Comment: you cannot remove the existing lens if you wish to retain the autofocus function ... that means that you cannot add a regular camera lens ... you would have to use the cell phone clip-on lens

Comment: @jsotola, yes, I'm keeping the current lens and adding another lens on top of it.